# How does one query the "parameters" sent to a Chromecast Reciever app?

Tags: google-cast

The docs shown on this page demonstrate how to send arbitrary parameters from a sender app to a receiver app:

https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender

Specifically, here:

request.parameters = "v=abcdefg";

But, I don't see how the receiver app is supposed to access those parameters once sent?  Does someone have an example of jscript for a receiver to see this string?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Chromecast pulls down the built-in application settings from the following URL: https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/device/config

If you take a look at that file, you'll notice that many of the URLs look like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/tv?${POST_DATA}

Notice that `${POST_DATA}` is specified as part of the URL that defines the application. I am only guessing, but I would assume that unless your application is setup similarly on Google's whitelist, that you'll be unable to receive that data via the URL.

It may be worth using a channel to send the data you require to your application instead of trying to use request.parameters.

Comment: Hopefully this will get added to the developer docs for the Chrome API soon, since I initially was wondering this same thing and just gave up trying to find it. You're probably right. It's unfortunate, because lots of people are going to copy/paste the sample YouTube receiver and then wonder how to access those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This should be passed in the query parameter section of the URL that the receiver loads. For example, if your app URL is:

```
http://example.com/foo.html
```

and you set:

```
request.parameters = "bar=baz";
```

then the full URL should come out as:

```
http://example.com/foo.html?bar=baz
```

From your receiver JavaScript, you can interrogate this value with [`document.location.search`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp).

Comment: That's what I suspected initially as well, but it is not the case (as far as I can tell).  When I interrogate the value of document.location, it returns "http://example.com/foo.html", without the "bar=baz" (using your example).  I can also see in the debugger that the baseURI does not contain any url query strings.  Normally, the chrome debugger includes any query strings in the url, so if it were included in the url, it would show up there.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's accessible in the loadedmetadata callback? I'll try this out later tonight and see if I can help figure it out.