# How to interact with RAMP in a custom receiver application for Chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I've created a custom sender and receiver applications for Chromecast.  The sender should be sending a url (dash mpd) over the wire.  The receiver should create a video element and upon receiving the dash mpd url create some extra files that interact with the video element.

On the sender I'm doing this:

```
var request = new cast.LaunchRequest(APP_ID, receiver);
request.parameters = params;
cast_api.launch(request, onLaunch);
```

Followed by:

```
var request = new cast.MediaLoadRequest("http://dash.edgesuite.net/envivio/dashpr/clear/Manifest.mpd");
request.parameters = params;
cast_api.loadMedia(cv_activity.activityId, request, onLoad);
```

Then in the receiver I have:

```
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(APP_ID, [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE]);
var rampHandler = new cast.receiver.RemoteMedia();
rampHandler.addChannelFactory(receiver.createChannelFactory(cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE));
rampHandler.onOpen = onOpen;
rampHandler.onMessage = onMessage;
rampHandler.onLoad = onLoad;
rampHandler.onInfo = onInfo;
rampHandler.onPlay = onPlay;
rampHandler.onStop = onStop;
rampHandler.onEnded = onEnded;
rampHandler.onMetadataLoaded = onMetadataLoaded;
rampHandler.onLoadMetaDataError = onLoadMetaDataError;
rampHandler.onVolume = onVolume;
```

onOpen and onMessage get fired once when I launch the receiver.  Nothing appears to happen after I call api.loadMedia.  From what I've read it appears that the api is accessing the RAMP calls which the RemoteMedia should respond to.  I'm expecting either onLoad or onMessage to get triggered after api.loadMedia is called..  But nothing happens.  There's no traces at all in the Chromecast debugger.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the debugger? Try going to http://<CAST_IP>:9222 and clicking the link on that simple HTML page to open a Chrome-like debugger. Go to the Network tab in that debugger view. Then, launch the session from the sender page. You should see some network traffic appear. One in particular looks like "session?1"; this is the WebSocket connection. If you click on it, then switch it from "Headers" to "Frame", you can see the JSON go back and forth. It won't update automatically, you have to click on it again in the Network traffic list.

Comment: I have been using the debugger, but I didn't know about the network traffic.  Good tip!  Nevertheless, it sadly did not help.  I don't see any messages after the api.loadMedia() is called.  The callback passed to api.loadMedia() does get called though, so something is happening... I just don't know what.

Comment: I'm also passing some parameters along with the LaunchRequest (in api.launch) and I don't see those parameters anywhere in the network traffic either..

Comment: Not sure, sounds like there might not be enough logic exposed to the debugging on either side to figure out what's up. I've found that the Chrome API is missing parameter validation and error messages, which means sometimes you can make a silly mistake and not catch it for a while. Regarding parameters, it might be that they are not getting passed, see discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18007132/48735

Comment: Ah, that may very well be the case.  I was also trying to use a custom channel, but I don't see any way in the Chrome Sender API to use them.  Perhaps the ability hasn't been exposed on the Chrome Sender API yet.

Comment: What do you mean by custom channel? The Chrome Sender API is missing a lot of details that are actually implemented. For one, api.addMessageListener lets you listen for custom messages. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is what I mean, but the other way around.  I saw your example at https://github.com/nickspacek/chromecast/tree/gh-pages and it has been very helpful.  I've got receiver -> sender messages working, but not sender -> receiver messages.  You can see my code at http://www.digitalprimates.net/dash/chromecast/receiver/js/main.js and http://www.digitalprimates.net/dash/chromecast/sender/js/caster.js.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35370/discussion-between-nick-spacek-and-nathan)

Comment: At the end of the day, my original question was not answered.  I was able to figure out how to send messages over a custom protocol however, which I was able to use to accomplish my goal.  One thing to point out is that I had some links with href="#" which causes the connection to Chromecast to break.

Comment: It would be great to summarize some of the obstacles that were overcame in an answer to this... with the Chrome API docs a little lacking, it would be useful to provide as much additional information on StackOverflow as possible. :)

Comment: To see the RAMP commands you can create your own version of Google's cast_receiver.js and add logging to that. Here is where I added mine: cr$.xa=function(a){console.log(a.data); this.dispatchEvent(new cr$Ob(a.data))};

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the object prototype:

```
cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.prototype.onLoad = onLoad
```